# Python Program counting and list question

Tags: python

I made a Python program to repeat the number of internships that I applied for, BUT I need it to store the amount I add so that I can ask it later how many I applied for, rather than me having to enter a number every time. Also, I want it to be able to update if the number of internships I applied for changes, I will input the new number of internships manually. How can I change my program to do that? Please take a look thanks

```
    print("Welcome back, Ryan")
internships = {} 
asking_ryan = True

amount = input("Enter how many internships you have applied for: ")
amount = int(amount)


if amount > 1:
    print("You have applied for: " + str(amount) + " internship(s)")
    str(amount)

if amount < 1:
    print("Error! you cannot apply for 0 internships!")


if amount == 1:
    print("You have applied for: " + str(amount) + " internship")
```

Program output: 
Welcome back, Ryan.

Enter how many internships you have applied for: 2

You have applied for: 2 internship(s)

Comment: do tutorials about   file operations and store stuff in a file. on start look for the file and read from it. look up int() for string to number conversion.

Comment: You could save this amount in a file and retrieve it later. If you never dealt with files in Python you can follow [this tutorial](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, I transform my comment to an answer and adding details so you can set your question as resolved.
EDIT : @OzonePrograms already gave you a good answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I saw your question. I kind of understand it.

You want to be able to update the internships you have done so you don't have to always rerun the program so it counts your internship?

You might have to use some files for that, should be simple!

First, you can make a file called `opens.txt` and add a 0 to the file that tracks how many times you opened that program. When you run the program do this:

```
opens = open("opens.txt", w+)
open_count = int(opens.read())
opens.write(open_count + 1)

if open_count == 1:
    amount = input("Enter how many internships you have applied for: ")
    ... # Other Code
```

Then make a file called something like `internships.txt` where it will store how many internships you currently have, default it to 0.

```
internships = open("internships.txt", w+)
internship_count = int(internships.read())

print("You currently have applied to {} internships since last time...".format(internship_count)

new_internships = input("How many new internships have you applied for?  ")

internships.write(internship_count + new_internships)
```

I think this should help? Haven't used files in a long time. Next time please phrase your question a bit better.